# Simple bookmarklet not working in chrome

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, bookmarklet

I am new to bookmarklet coding and i have run into a problem where the regular javascript works fine in the browser but not the bookmarklet version.

I had found a bookmarklet which finds a image and turns it into BB code and that works fine, however it loads jQuery and i did not want it doing that all the time. So i was basically just trying to remove the need for it but now it does not work anymore as a bookmarklet.

The original bookmarklet was this:

```
javascript:document.body.appendChild(document.createElement('script')).src='http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4/jquery.min.js';var%20pictureurl=jQuery('img[id$=%22myImage%22]').attr('src');var%20linkurl=document.location.href;alert('%5BURL='+linkurl+'%5D%5BIMG%5D'+pictureurl+'%5B%2FIMG%5D%5B%2FURL%5D');
```

My javascript which works as regular JS code is:

```
// Create array variables
var imgs = [];

// Put all of the documents tags in to the arrays
imgs = document.getElementsByTagName('img');

var pictureurl = '';
var linkurl = document.location.href;

for(var i = 0; i < imgs.length; i++){
    var str = imgs[i].getAttribute('id');
    var find = str.search("myImage"); 
    if(find != -1){
        pictureurl = imgs[i].getAttribute('src');
        alert('[URL=' + linkurl + '][IMG]' + pictureurl + '[/IMG][/URL]');
    }
}
```

When i add javascript: and append the minimized code i can not get it working no matter what i try. If anyone could help me get this working that would be a big help, thanks.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Yeah, you have an error in your code. I would like to show you how to find it yourself rather than just say where it is, so here goes a micro-tutorial ;)

1. Strip line comments (`//`) from your JS code as the bookmarklet will be on one line. You should end up with the code:

   ```
   var imgs = [];
   imgs = document.getElementsByTagName('img');
   var pictureurl = '';
   var linkurl = document.location.href;
   for(var i = 0; i < imgs.length; i++){
       var str = imgs[i].getAttribute('id');
       var find = str.search("myImage"); 
       if(find != -1){
           pictureurl = imgs[i].getAttribute('src');
           alert('[URL=' + linkurl + '][IMG]' + pictureurl + '[/IMG][/URL]');
       }
   }
   ```
2. Remove *new line* characters from the code and prefix the code with `javascript:` protocol so that Chrome knows that the contents is JavaScript code. Your code should now look like this:

   ```
   javascript: var imgs = []; imgs = document.getElementsByTagName('img'); var pictureurl = ''; var linkurl = document.location.href; for(var i = 0; i < imgs.length; i++){     var str = imgs[i].getAttribute('id');     var find = str.search("myImage");      if(find != -1){         pictureurl = imgs[i].getAttribute('src');         alert('[URL=' + linkurl + '][IMG]' + pictureurl + '[/IMG][/URL]');     } }
   ```
3. Create your bookmarklet as a bookmark and make sure its accessible (i.e. visible so you can click it in any Chrome window).
4. Go to a page on which you will test your bookmarklet code.
5. Open *Developer tools* by holding <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>SHIFT</kbd> + <kbd>I</kbd>.
6. Switch to the tab named *Console*.
7. Click the bookmarklet.
8. The console should now show you the errors/warnings that have been issued while executing the code of your bookmarlet.
9. In case of your code, it spits:

   ```
   Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'search' of null (program):1
   (anonymous function)
   ```

Which seems reasonable since `search()` is invoked on the value of `str` which contains a value of `ID` attribute, but not all `IMG` tags have an `id` assigned.

What's cool is that you can click on the `(program):1` on the right hand side of the window and debug the code, inspect variables, etc.

Comment: Well i tried the steps but console did not show that error, there were page errors and a bubble that says 7 but i cannot seem to expand it.

Comment: @zeddex "Bubble"? Page errors may appear due to e.g. resources that failed to load (like images with wrong URLs). Can you post a screenshot? What Chrome version are you using?

Comment: Apparently version 22.0.1229.94 m

Comment: Edit - Actually it works i just forgot getAttribute('id') later, so it seems to be fixed now. Now idea why the console does not work for me but i have solved this now thanks to you pointing out the error. :)

Comment: @zeddex I've updated the answer, check if you've followed steps 1 and 2 and the code you get is the same. I'm running 24.0.1312.52 m. Yes, a working fix is to check if `str != null`. I think you're doing something wrong earlier - my colleagues tested resulting bookmarklet from step 2 and it's also working for them.

Answer (score 4):

note that this code

```
javascript:alert('hi');
```

wont work unless if there is any visible page
i.e try to go to any website first

when i first try it nothing was happening , then when i tried the same code in an existing page it worked

Comment: This is explained in detail in [this post](/a/72223376)